# Expo Local Authentication not working for non-Biometric devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, authentication, expo

I am using expo local authentication in an expo project and it works perfectly with IOS/Android, But for older android devices that doesn't have Face/Touch ID its not possible to use local authentication and gives this error:

```
Object {
  "error": "not_available",
  "message": "Biometric hardware unavailable",
  "success": false,
}
```

I tested in expo SDK 38 and 39, with expo-local-authentication version 9.2.0 and 9.3.0 .

Any help how can i use Pin/Pattern for older non-biometric devices?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Local authentication package only does biometric, it won't just do device pin without having biometric hardware.

to guard against older devices, you simply use the following methods to disable the biometric code.

```
LocalAuthentication.hasHardwareAsync();
```

and

```
LocalAuthentication.isEnrolledAsync()
```

both return a promise, so you need to await for them.

```
if (await LocalAuthentication.isEnrolledAsync() && await LocalAuthentication.isEnrolledAsync()) {
  //do biometric auth
} else {
  // implement your own password or use another package for device pin.
}
```